# Wordpress sort posts by selected custom field

Tags: wordpress

I want to sort some `custom posts type` by a `ACF select` custom field. I try it from `ACF` documentation but it didn't work, results appeared in the same order. 
The select field contains number from 1 to 30 and they should represent the position of a post. 
My code for `query args`:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'opalsgevent_speaker',
    'posts_per_page'    => $count,
    'meta_key'          => 'ordine',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
    'order'             => 'ASC'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would check if meta_key name is correct.

And next: maybe they are sorted but not in the way as you expect. From [WP_Query documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query):

> 'meta_value' - (...) the sorting will be alphabetical which is fine for strings (i.e. words), but can be unexpected for numbers (e.g. 1, 3, 34, 4, 56, 6, etc, rather than 1, 3, 4, 6, 34, 56 as you might naturally expect). Use 'meta_value_num' instead for numeric values.

So not `meta_value` but `meta_value_num`

Comment: I've tried both `meta_value` and `meta_value_num`, also I've checked and `meta_key` is correct. And no, they are no sorted, they are exactly like before, position didn't change at all.

Comment: what happens when you try to get this meta_value? like `echo get_post_meta(some-post-id, 'ordine', true);`? maybe this is not a number actually but some array of numbers or object

Comment: The strange thing is it returns the correct number... :(. That's why I susspect that select field works differently.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to use 'meta_value_num" instead of 'meta_value':

```
'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

Comment: I've tried both `meta_value` and `meta_value_num`, still not work.